# Creating an index page automatically

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'd like to have dotnetnuke build an index page based on pages that have a particular tabid. Are there any modules that do this already?

e.g. we create multiple pages under /News and then the index page lists links to all the news articles. Would be handy if we could also enter our own HTML text (maybe on the News article page itself) that is then displayed next to each link on the index page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there are no 'real' pages in DNN.  Everything is served up in the Default.aspx from content that is stored in the database.

What you could do is create a module that populates data based on the TabId or Path.  Then, there is a setting in DNN to make a module appear on EVERY page.  Since the module is on every page, it could populate its data based on the TabId or the path, or just not show anything if it doesn't match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

For something like that, I used a module called SQLGridSelectedView from www.tressleworks.ca (I have no affiliation) and I wrote my own SQL to fill in the fields, and I defined a custom layout (instead of the default data grid) so I was able to do something like what you are asking without code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module from Ventrian called [Child Links](http://www.ventrian.com/modules/child-links) that does what you are talking about.  You can use it to grab title & description from the pages below a relative to a specific page to build out menus etc.

It allows for formatting however you want as well.